# How to override a default class attribute value in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Python noob here. I'm working on a "Text Adventure" type game. I'm currently attempting to build a class for game items, with various default attributes for these items. One of these attributes will be a boolean "takeable", to indicate if the player can take this item or not. I've managed to make this work but only if I assign `True` or `False` to `takeable` for every item I create. I've figured out how to default to `takeable=False` but it seems I can't selectively pass `takeable=True` for the few items that are "takeable."

```
class Objects():
    """Basic structure of all game objects."""

    def __init__(self, item_name, item_description):
        self.item_name = item_name
        self.item_description = item_description
        self.takeable = False


items = {
    "main_room_table": Objects("Wooden table", "A large wooden table with items scatter atop its surface."),
    "main_room_key": Objects("Small brass key", "A small brass skeleton key. What could it unlock?", takeable=True)
```

This causes a `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'takeable'` I understand this is happening because I'm passing the argument `takeable=True` when Python isn't expecting another argument.

Is there a way override a default value like this during the creation of the class instance? I understand I could just require a boolean of `takeable` be passed each time I create a new "item" instance, but it seems there would be a way to default to a value and be able to override it in the creation of a class instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default values are assigned to arguments, not inside the init definition.

```
class Objects():
    """Basic structure of all game objects."""

    def __init__(self, item_name, item_description, takeable=False):
        self.item_name = item_name
        self.item_description = item_description
        self.takeable = takeable


items = {
    "main_room_table": Objects("Wooden table", "A large wooden table with items scatter atop its surface."),
    "main_room_key": Objects("Small brass key", "A small brass skeleton key. What could it unlock?", takeable=True),
}
```

Another way would have been setting it after creation but that would require it to do it outside the `dict` with `items["main_room_key"].takeable = True`

Comment: This is what I needed. I misunderstood where to place "takeable=False". Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Your `__init__` doesn't accept a `takeable`-parameter. You can make it an optional argument (defaulting to `False`, if not given):

```
def __init__(self, item_name, item_description, takeable=False):
    [...]
    self.takeable = takeable
```

Answer (score 0):

You are literally describing default arguments:

```
class Objects():
    """Basic structure of all game objects."""

    def __init__(self, item_name, item_description, takeable=False):
        self.item_name = item_name
        self.item_description = item_description
        self.takeable = takeable
```

now you can choose, or not, to provide `takeable` as a value, and, if not, it takes the value `False`.